# set max value of input box based on the selected checkbox in angular js

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, input

I have created a table which displays units, amounts , checkbox1forunits , checkbox2foramounts , input. the table has four records. the value of units and amounts come from the json array.

I want to set the max of input box based on the selected checkbox. for each input box there is different max value. if checkbox1forunits  is selected then set max of input box to the corresponding given unit.
if checkbox2foramounts  is selected then set max of input box to the corresponding  given amount.

what condition should I write to achieve this? I understand the logic but having difficulty writing it in angular js.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.IsVisible = false;
            $scope.GenerateTable = function () {
                $scope.Customers = [
                {unit: 100, amount: 1000},
                { unit: 200,amount: 2000},
                {unit: 300,amount: 3000},
                { unit: 400,amount: 4000}
               ];

                $scope.IsVisible = true;
              };    
        });

        app.directive("limitToMax", function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      element.on("keydown keyup", function(e) {

    if (Number(element.val()) > Number(attributes.max) &&
          e.keyCode != 46 // delete
          &&
          e.keyCode != 8 // backspace
        ) {
          scope.val=true;
          e.preventDefault();
          element.val(attributes.max);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});

    </script>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <input type="button" value="Generate Table" ng-click="GenerateTable()" />
        <hr />
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ng-show="IsVisible">
            <tr>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Checkbox1</th>
                <th>Checkbox2</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{m.unit}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.amount}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"ng-model="checkbox1[$m]"</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"ng-model="checkbox2[$m]"</td>
                    <td><input type="number" ng-model="myVar[$m]" min="1" max="{{m.unit}}" limit-to-max /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for single row, any one checkbox will be active? checkbox1forunits or checkbox2foramounts. right?

Comment: right only one will be active

Comment: added my answer. please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, for single row, any one checkbox will be active? checkbox1forunits or checkbox2foramounts.

This is achievable using `ng-change` in `checkbox` and tenerary operator in `max` attribute

Please find the working example below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
    app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
      $scope.IsVisible = false;
      $scope.GenerateTable = function() {
        $scope.Customers = [{
          unit: 100,
          amount: 1000
        }, {
          unit: 200,
          amount: 2000
        }, {
          unit: 300,
          amount: 3000
        }, {
          unit: 400,
          amount: 4000
        }];

        $scope.IsVisible = true;
      };
    });

    app.directive("limitToMax", function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
          element.on("keydown keyup", function(e) {

            if (Number(element.val()) > Number(attributes.max) &&
              e.keyCode != 46 // delete
              &&
              e.keyCode != 8 // backspace
            ) {
              scope.val = true;
              e.preventDefault();
              element.val(attributes.max);
            }
          });
        }
      };
    });
  </script>
  <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="button" value="Generate Table" ng-click="GenerateTable()" />
    <hr />
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ng-show="IsVisible">
      <tr>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Checkbox1</th>
        <th>Checkbox2</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
        <tr>
          <td>{{m.unit}}</td>
          <td>{{m.amount}}</td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-init="checkbox1[$m] = true" ng-model="checkbox1[$m]" ng-change="checkbox2[$m] = !checkbox1[$m]"/> </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox2[$m]" ng-change="checkbox1[$m] = !checkbox2[$m]"/> </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" ng-model="myVar[$m]" min="1" max="{{checkbox1[$m]?m.unit:m.amount}}" limit-to-max />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```